# Start Google Chrome from Applescript and set position

Tags: applescript

I am making a startup script to start various applications and set their locations and size. It works for everything except chrome. I need a script that checks if Chrome is open, and if it is open the current window, if it isnt activate it. Then, set its size and position

```
-- Start terminal 
tell application "Terminal"
    if (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    do script "screenfetch"
end tell

delay .5

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
    tell window 1
        set size to {960, 600}
        set position to {2880, 0}
    end tell
end tell

delay .5


-- Start Chrome
tell application "Google Chrome"
    if (exists window 1) then
        reopen
    else
        activate
    end if
end tell

delay .5

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
    tell front window
        set size to {960, 600}
        set position to {1920, 0}
    end tell
end tell
delay .5
```

This works for Terminal. It starts a terminal and puts it in the top right of my second monitor. However, with Chrome it will either: say "cannot find Window 1 of Chrome" or, it will bring chrome to the front and won't set its size or position.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, it's best to simply tell the application to do something directly rather than trying to route it through System Events. In this case, Google Chrome supports the basic `window` object from AppleScript's standard suite, so you can do something like the following:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    if ((count of windows) = 0) then
        make new window with properties {bounds:{1920, 22, 960, 622}}
    else
        set bounds of window 1 to {1920, 22, 960, 622}
    end if
end tell
```